# Navigation panel in backoffice is empty

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Backoffice panel is totally empty with no reason. See the picture below:
[image]

The funny thing is that backoffice panel does not work only on my machine (locally). Other team members do not encounter this problem, however, we are working on the same project with the same repo. So, I think that the problem sits locally, but I can't imagine where exactly, because all the functionality that do not come out of the box is stored in the remote repo.
And if you clean your workspace, update project from remote and perform "ant clena all" and run the server, then for me backoffice panel does not work, but for other team members it works correctly.
**Have anyone encountered the same problem?**

**UPDATED:**
This is what I got after first try of resetting configs:
[image]
and this is the second try:
[image]
**nothing is changed.**

**below you can see the stack trace with the warning itself:**
[image]
[image]

**SOLVED:**
The problem was sitting in the database I have used **MySQL** 5.6 and the other 3 members 8.x, for us Backoffice didn't work -> for others who uses 5.7 or 5.6.45 it works fine. It is a little bit strange and I did not find any information regarding to third party compatibilities on the official sites of hybris. There is only installation recommendation for the MySQL but no version recommendations and which is more stable...

Comment: Backoffice template is loaded and stored in browser local storage. Can you try to access it in incognito mode and confirm if you face the issue there as well?

Comment: I have tried that, no, it didn't work - still empty panel. The stack trace is the same as the last picture in the question post.

Answer (score 1):

Without the error log, it's hard to say what's the root cause. But I must suggest resting all config from Backoffice orchestrator mode.

1. Press F4 to open Orchestrator mode when you are in the Backoffice
2. Now click on Hybris log located at the top right corner, you can see Rest Everything option in the dropdown.
3. Click on Rest Everything and let the system reset all Backoffice config.
4. Exit Orchestrator mode by again pressing F4

Comment: I have already done it several times, some team members have experienced the same problem and it took about 30 minutes to make backoffice working -> reset all Backoffice config, about 10-20 times and in one of them the panel is loaded. If you try to do it after the panel is loaded in most cases you would come back to the empty panel again...

Answer (score 1):

That's a tricky one. It could be due to broken configuration template references.

Try following

**Option 1 :**

1. Go to admin console -> select all backoffice related extensions and do a system update **[TRY IT FIRST]**

**Option 2 :**

1. Remove `HYBIRS_HOME/temp` ,
   `HYBRIS_HOME/data/media/sys_master/backofficeconfiguration` and `HYBRIS_HOME/data/backoffice`

[image]

[image]

2. Run `ant clean all` followed by a hybris restart.
3. Go to hac -> select all backoffice related extensions and do a system update

Hopefully that should fix it. Good luck!

Comment: No, it also did not help. I have asked other colleagues who has the same problem they told me that they have completely reinstalled hybris with the project and set it up from the scratch and it also does not help. As I understood correctly, we are not tried only one thing - reinstall the entire OS, but it would be nightmare to set up all the things needed for developing from the start. At this point I really don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Btw I did not find this folder `backofficeconfiguration` in my project dir.

Comment: Uninstalling OS doesn't seem to be logical. Hybris creates various files for BO under media folder and in data. Resetting that with above steps should help. And  trying removing browser cache and data would be needed to. Which version of hybris you are using? You should find in data/media/*backoffice *

Comment: The version that we are using - 6.7 . I have the following structure: `C:\Project\hybris\data\media\sys_master or (sys_junit)\**` and in sys_master dir there is no folder which name contains backoffice word.

Comment: Got it.. you will have to delete following 1) `C:\Project\hybris\data\backoffice` and 2) `C:\Project\hybris\data\media\sys_master\backofficeconfiguration`. Updated the answer.

Comment: In this dir `C:\Project\hybris\data\media\sys_master\`` there is no backofficeconfiguration folder :(. There are cronjob, images, impex and a lot of folders that starts with `h` char

Comment: Strange, I checked with 6.7 setup and I could see it in my version. Are you sure that you are able to run system update successfully by selecting all backoffice related extensions in your project? This folder should generate during init or update as hybris creates BO media in there.

Comment: I've checked it on other colleagues  computers which backoffice works fine and I didn't find there `backofficeconfiguration` folder.

Comment: Apologies as couldn't think of anything else. I have checked in 6.7 travel and 1811 b2c setup and i see these files over there. I will get back after restoring my b2c/b2b setup on hybris 6.7. Another possibility is that in your local, you have some broken backoffice config xml. Check carefully for warnings and error when you try to reset configuration.  Till then, Good luck

Comment: Hi @Maksim - Might see it as a workaround if you still face the problem. It would be quicker to copy data folder from your colleague's machine and copy in your hybris... :)